# How to create maven project with GlassFish?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I start Java web project and I accustomed use maven for assemble my project. But when I open window for select project type I see:

[image]

My type **Web Application** in **Java Enterprise** section. And I need select web or maven.

How to create web project(I need GlassFish for Web-Socket) *with* the opportunity use maven?

Comment: Try selecting "Maven" on the sidebar instead of "Java Enterprise"

Comment: @OndrejM this is obviously) But then my project structure completely different from Web Application type .

Comment: Maven requires a different project structure threfore yes, your project structure would be different from Web Application Type. But Idea will know how to work with it and if you create a maven project with WAR packaging, it will treat it as a Web Application.